# How to send long Ajax responses?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

My problem is that my HTTP server needs to send a long string as the response to a AJAX POST request. The browser (Google Chrome) doesn't receive the whole payload. For some reason it receives like 50 characters less and the response message is cut off randomly in the middle of a word or something. The response message contains letters, numbers, spaces and these symbols/characters: `;?/ÄÖÜäöüß` ; no CR and no LF.

**What can I do to get the whole string over to the client?**
After more testing I figured the problem is something with encoding of characters like `äöü`. I've got no solution for it yet besides avoiding the use of those characters.

**An example response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 2616

... here the long string of 2616 characters ...
```

**Ajax:**

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", host, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    that.status = http.status;
    if (http.readyState == 4)
    {
        if (http.responseText.length > 1000)
            alert(http.responseText.length);
        that.result = http.responseText.trim();
        if (replyHandler != null)
            replyHandler(that);
    }
}
http.send(that.toString());
```

Comment: what is the response from the server without ajax (if you call it directly) ?

Comment: Something else is wrong in your setup. Chrome most certainly can handle 2KB and larger payloads. What's the outcome of not using 206?

Comment: Ok, I noticed that my response messages are getting cut off. Could that be a encoding problem? Yet all the characters like 'äöü' are received fine at the client side. I edited the question.

Comment: Given that content-length is size of response in bytes and that some encodings can use more than one byte per char I would suggest checking how your server calculates response size.